# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0): TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate')

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to display an image I have captured using expo-camera, from the camera component I'm trying to navigate to a new file which will display the image but after I took the image it won't navigate to the new page.

I tried importing the file and then navigate it but it still won't work and give me the warning instead.

This is the code where I tried to navigate to the new file.

```
    export default class CameraExample extends React.Component {
  state = {
    hasCameraPermission: null,
    type: Camera.Constants.Type.back,
  };

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ hasCameraPermission: status === 'granted' });
  }

  snap = async() => {
      if(this.camera) {
          console.log('Taking photo');
          const options = {quality: 1, base64: true, fixOrientation: true, exif: true};
          const photo = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
          this.props.navigation.navigate("Show", {photouri: photo.uri})
      }
  }

  render() {
    const { hasCameraPermission } = this.state;
    if (hasCameraPermission === null) {
      return <View />;
    } else if (hasCameraPermission === false) {
      return <Text>No access to camera</Text>;
    } else {
      return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Camera style={{ flex: 1 }} type={this.state.type}
            ref = {ref => {
                this.camera = ref;
            }}
          >
            <View
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                flexDirection: 'row',
              }}>

              <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.snap.bind(this)}>
                  <Ionicons
                    name = "md-camera"
                    color = "white"
                    size = {30}
                  />
              </TouchableOpacity>

              <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                  flex: 0.1,
                  alignSelf: 'flex-end',
                  alignItems: 'center',
                }}
                onPress={() => {
                  this.setState({
                    type:
                      this.state.type === Camera.Constants.Type.back
                        ? Camera.Constants.Type.front
                        : Camera.Constants.Type.back,
                  });
                }}>
                <Ionicons
                    name = "md-reverse-camera"
                    color = "white"
                    size = {30}
                />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </Camera>
        </View>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the code where I try to display the image.

```
export default class ShowImages extends React.Component{
    render(){ 
       console.log('OK')
       const { navigation } = this.props;
       const paramm = navigation.getParam('photouri');
        return(
            <Content>
                <View>
                    <Text>
                        paramm: {JSON.stringify(paramm)}
                    </Text>
                    <Image style={{height: 700, width: 850, alignSelf: "center"}}
                    source={{uri: this.props.navigation.state.paramm.photouri}}
                    resizeMode="contain"/>
                </View>
            </Content>
        )
    }
}
```

I expect it to navigate to the new page and display the captured 
image but it gave me the warning. I can't seem to find what is wrong with my code. Can anyone suggest what I should do? Thank you.

Comment: Whichever component the `snap` component method is defined in is not receiving `navigation` as a prop. Please provide more info on that component and how it is being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```js
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.snap.bind(this)}> =>  <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.snap}>
```

Put it in the status value and pass it on.

```js
export default class ShowImages extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      paramm: this.props.navigation.state.params.photouri
    };
  }
...
                    <Image style={{height: 700, width: 850, alignSelf: "center"}}
                    source={{uri: this.state.paramm }}
                    resizeMode="contain"/>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for answering. I changed my code to yours but I still get the same warning and it doesn't display my image. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: Your warning is a matter of moving the screen.

Comment: @karxav  Please show the full code on the moving screen.

Comment: Do you mean the code where I capture the image? I'm sorry, I'm new to this so I might be using your code incorrectly.

Comment: @karxav I want to see the screen code that executes the Move Screen command.

Comment: Are the screens configured with a stack navigator?

Comment: Yes, it is configured with a stack navigator

Comment: @karxav Please show me the code with the screen sending the image data.

Comment: Is this what you mean?

export default class ShowImages extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            paramm: this.props.navigation.state.params.photouri
        };
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <View>
                <Image style={{height: 700, width: 850, alignSelf: "center"}}
                    source={{uri: this.state.paramm}}
                    resizeMode="contain"/>
                </View>
        )
    }
}

Comment: It's not the screen, it's the screen that commands you to go to the Show screen.

Comment: @karxav I modified my answer. Look at the top answer code.

Comment: Can you please show me how to exactly modify my code like yours? The one where I'm trying to display my image. Sorry to keep bothering, thank you.

Comment: @karxav I modified the answer to make it easier for you to know. Do you understand?

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant the export default one.

Comment: Hello! Thank you so much for helping me earlier. Your code helped me improve my code. I hope you have a great day. :)